# Virtual Display but with GPU/Hardware Acceleration

Tags: chrome, vnc, gpu, xvfb, selenium

To do some automated screen recordings for promo videos of web applications I'm using chromium/selenium inside of xvfb to run the web application and ffmpeg to record the video. Even tough this looks ok, sometimes it seems to be laggy during some animation-intense scenes most likely due to missing gpu/hardware acceleration.

Is there any alternative to run an application with gpu/hardware acceleration headless?